# Find a hidden field whose id is partly known inside a known div using jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a situation where the id of a div is known and only part of the id of an embedded hidden field is known.

**Question**

What jQuery selector will help me find a hidden field that has *2df_20* in its id within a div having an id of *panel1*? The html for this situation is as given below.

```
<div id="panel1">
  <input type='hidden' name='mydiv1_abc_1' value='prod1' />
  <input type='hidden' name='mydiv1_xyz_12'  value='prod2' />
  <input type='hidden' name='mydiv1_2df_20'  value='prod3' />
</div>
<div id="panel2">
  <input type='hidden' name='mydiv2_abc_1' value='prod1' />
  <input type='hidden' name='mydiv2_xyz_12'  value='prod2' />
  <input type='hidden' name='mydiv2_2df_20'  value='prod3' />
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select using [attribute contains selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/):

```
$('#panel1 input[name*="2df_20"]')
```

There are other attribute selectors. Look [here](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/) for full list of attribute selectors.

Comment: Should not the name* be replaced by id*, since a part of the id is known?